# Como obter dados de formulário via "POST"?

Tags: java, html, jsf, post

Há alguma forma de receber dados vindos de um formulário externo utilizando o `method="post"` em minha página jsf?

Já consigo fazer isso quando os dados trafegam via `GET`.

```java
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="dados" value="#{testeMB.dadoExterno}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Tentei redirecionar via `jQuery` adicionando as variaveis ao HEADER assim (de acordo com a dica do @uaiHebert):

```js
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "http://www.dominio.com.br:8888/sistema/home.jsf",
headers: {
    "login": "user",
    "senha": "1234",
}
```

Mas ocorre o erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.dominio.com.br:8888/sistema/home.jsf.
>
> The request was redirected to 'http://www.dominio.com.br:8888/sistema/login.jsf;jsessionid=B29848B037ABA032CDD9B358842F929B?windowId=d67', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Comment: Desculpe, mas qual o motivo pelo post especificamente?

Comment: Acontece que tenho uma página de login, mas um dos requisitos que tenho é que o login possa ser feito através de um formulário localizado num site qualquer. Como serão trafegados login e senha, preciso que seja via post.

Comment: Já fiz com que minha tela de login receba os dados via get e faça o login automaticamente... agora preciso receber isso via post por segurança (caso contrário os dados ficarão expostos na URL)

Comment: Você não poderia passar os valores no header então?

Comment: Passar no header? Como assim? Não seria o mesmo que enviar via GET. Ex: http://dominio.com.br/servico.jsf?var1=1&var2=x... ?

Comment: Quando o formulário que for disparar a chamada de login, você via javascript/jquery/angular sei lá adicionaria o header no request. Não é o mesmo que enviar via GET pois um HEADER não vai na URL.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste...

Comment: @uaiHebert não consegui, veja o erro que apresenta.

Comment: Realmente, comi mosca nessa. Se não me engano, por ajax, você não consegue redirecionar chamadas para outros domínios. -___-''

Comment: O que eu consigo pensar então é você ter um redirect para o site e o login ser feito no site.

Comment: Pois é... hoje eu tenho essas duas alternativas: Direcionar para a página de login do sistema ou disparar o login via site externo com as variáveis na URL, via GET. Mas estas formas sempre são questionadas.

Comment: Achei o Omnifaces (showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam) que consegue ler os atributos via POST, mas aparentemente o Omnifaces conflita com o OpenWebBeans (CDI) que eu uso.

Comment: Passando via post você adiciona uma pseudo proteção pois os dados não ficarão visíveis, por exemplo, na barra de endereços e no histórico, mas um attack "man in the middle" pode revelar os dados se você não estiver usando uma conexão criptografada (SSL ou TLS por exemplo). @uaiHebert você quer dizer um header http? certamente não é a maneira apropriada.

Comment: Sobre o segundo erro, você dificilmente vai conseguir que o navegador permita um request HTTP cross-domínio. Veja por exemplo: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html e http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Como o @DiegoCNascimento disse, seu programa não é relacionado ao JSF ou ao Java, mas sim a restrições de segurança dos nevagadores que não permitem você fazer Ajax para outros domínios via javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Sobre como acessar dados recebidos via POST, você pode usar a anotação [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html):

```java
public class ManagedBean {
    @ManagedProperty("#{param.usuario}")
    private String usuario;

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.senha}")
    private String senha;

    // getters & setters aqui
}
```

Deve funcionar para parâmetros tanto via POST ou via GET.

Sobre a questão de fazer Ajax via jQuery, isso será meio complicado no seu caso porque as requisições POST para páginas JSF (*JSF postbacks*) usam maneiras bem singulares de montar as requisições, devido ao controle de *viewstate*. Em geral, é mais fácil usar o mecanismo de AJAX do próprio JSF, seja usando f:ajax ou outros componentes ou então usando as funções do [jsf.js](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/symbols/src/_Users_edburns_Documents_Projects_JavaEE_workareas_mojarra-HEAD_jsf-api_src_main_resources_jsf.js.html).

**Veja também:**

- [Diferenças entre f:viewParam e @ManagedProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889226/149872) (em inglês)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) (em inglês)
- [What is viewstate, and how it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910741/what-is-viewstate-in-jsf-and-how-is-it-used) (em inglês)

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Este não é um erro do JSF ou do Java, mas uma questão de segurança da internet ao tentar-se fazer Ajax para outro domínio.

Soluções incluem alterar o servidor de destino para permitir o Ajax, usar o seu servidor como uma espécie de intermediário para fazer a autenticação no servidor de destino ou ainda criar dinamicamente um formulário HTML em sua página e fazer um submit no mesmo.

## O motivo do erro

O erro apresentado na pergunta diz que a requisição (*request*) não foi permitida (*disallowed*) por ser para um domínio diferente (*cross-origin*). Quando você tenta fazer um Ajax para um outro domínio, o navegador por padrão irá negar essa chamada por questões de segurança.

Por outro lado, existe uma exceção a esta regra, no caso do outro servidor retornar  cabeçalhos específicos como `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` e `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, os quais podem autorizar determinadas ações. Basicamente, antes de executar o Ajax, o navegador faz uma pré-checagem (pre-flight) procurando por esses cabeçalhos. Veja o funcionamento no seguinte diagrama:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Este artigo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) explica muito bem a questão.

## Solução #1 - Permitir requisições de outro domínio

A primeira solução é alterar o servidor de destino para permitir as ações necessárias. Isso é explicado no artigo mencionado no tópico anterior.

Entretanto, no seu caso parece não ser viável nem possível, já que isso teria que ser feito em "um site qualquer" (vide comentário).

## Solução #2 - Criar um serviço intermediário

Poderia ser feira uma requisição Ajax ao seu próprio servidor, o que seria completamente permitido pelas regras de segurança, e então seu servidor fazia uma requisição ao outro site para fazer a autenticação e retornaria os resultados para sua página.

Pense em um Servlet que funciona como um proxy ou intermediário:

1. Ele recebe a requisição POST do Ajax
2. Efetua uma conexão POST com os mesmos dados no site alvo
3. Recebe a resposta do site
4. Retorna a mesma resposta para o Ajax

## Solução #3 - Usar um formulário oculto

Uma última alternativa seria criar dinamicamente um formulário oculto onde:

- O `action` é a página do outro site que verifica o login
- Os valores de login vão em campos `hidden`
- O `target` é um `iframe` também oculto, de modo a não interferir na página local

[Esta resposta no StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169703/1683070) desenvolve um pouco esta técnica. Só vai dar um pouco mais de trabalho capturar o retorno do *submit* de dentro do formulário.